# How to correctly configure a chain of AVAudioUnitEffects

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, avaudioengine

The following code configures the iOS audio engine to create samplers which are setup with one sound font (for simplicity of discussion). I then use the samples to play MIDI notes and all works well until I try to introduce a chain of standard effects (distortion -> delay -> reverb).

If the output of samplers is simply connected direct to the audio engine MainMixerNode it works. If I connect the samplers to the distortion effect (the first effect in the chain) then as soon as I attempt to play the first MIDI note I get error " AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument.mm:103: -[AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument startNote:withVelocity:onChannel:]: error -10867"

NOTE: I code using Xamarin on Mac, so the following may look unfamiliar but I hope the code is readable enough for your to assist.

The question is simply where am I going wrong in initialising my effects / or chain thereof?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

---

```
    private void InitAudioEngine(NSUrl sampleFileUrl)
    {
        AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().Init ();

        NSError sessionErrorCode;
        sessionErrorCode = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance ().SetCategory (AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
        if(sessionErrorCode != null)
            Logger.Write ("Failed to set AudioSession category");

        sessionErrorCode = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance ().SetActive (true);
        if(sessionErrorCode != null)
            Logger.Write ("Failed to activate AudioSession");

        Logger.Write ("Instantiate Audio Engine");

        _audioEngine = new AVAudioEngine ();
        _samplers = new List<AVAudioUnitSampler> ();

        var distortion = new AVAudioUnitDistortion ();
        var delay = new AVAudioUnitDelay ();
        var reverb = new AVAudioUnitReverb ();

        distortion.Init ();
        delay.Init ();
        reverb.Init ();

        distortion.LoadFactoryPreset (AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset.SpeechGoldenPi);
        reverb.LoadFactoryPreset (AVAudioUnitReverbPreset.LargeHall2);

        delay.DelayTime = 300;
        delay.WetDryMix = 30;
        delay.Feedback = 30;

        _audioEngine.AttachNode (distortion);
        _audioEngine.AttachNode (delay);
        _audioEngine.AttachNode (reverb);

        _audioEngine.Connect (distortion, delay, delay.GetBusOutputFormat (0));
        _audioEngine.Connect (delay, reverb, reverb.GetBusOutputFormat (0));
        _audioEngine.Connect (reverb, _audioEngine.MainMixerNode, _audioEngine.MainMixerNode.GetBusOutputFormat (0));

        for (int index = 0; index < 15; index++) 
        {
            var sampler = new AVAudioUnitSampler ();
            sampler.Init ();

            _samplers.Add (sampler);
            _audioEngine.AttachNode (sampler);
            _audioEngine.Connect (sampler, distortion, distortion.GetBusOutputFormat(0));
        }

        // Connect all the samplers to a defined SoundFont
        ConnectSoundbank (sampleFileUrl);

        NSError engineErrorCode;
        _audioEngine.StartAndReturnError (out engineErrorCode);

        if(engineErrorCode != null)
            Logger.Write ("Failed to start AudioEngine after samplers attached");
    }

// ...
// Later code
// Play a MIDI note on one of the samplers configured above
//
_samplers[0].StartNote(58,127,0); // Crashes with error -10867 (uninitialised)
//...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was trying to feed multiple samplers into each effect. It seems you need to create a Delay/Reverb/Distortion per Sampler.

Basically the signal chain needs to be Sampler -> Distortion -> Delay -> Reverb -> Mixer.

There's some assumptions in the statements above, I may be wrong if you can connect multiple samplers to a Delay using multiple input busses on the delay for example. But I couldn't be bothered testing to that extent.

Once I went with the one to one mapping my code worked.

So the AvAudioUnitXXXX effects must be created and connected inside the loop.

Comment: As soon as I have my git repos aligned I'll post the code.